# Обнаружить ошибку или каким должен быть код у начинающих JS?

Tags: javascript, dom

Постепенно я решаю, не без помощи этого сайта, мелкие задачки для достижения решения одной большой задачи. Сейчас после написания около 50 строк кода, обнаружил ошибку, которую из-за малого опыта не могу определить.

- Ошибка появляется, когда ввёл данные в textarea, далее 2 раза кликнул на кнопку отправить, а потом решил удалить появившиеся новые элементы нажатием на крестик. Одна вставка с элементами удаляется, другая нет.
- Как писать JS правильно чтобы не возникало ошибок вроде моей?

```js
  var submit = document.getElementById('submit');//записал в переменную кнопку "Отправить"
  submit.addEventListener('click', handler);//добавляем событие и обработчик

  function handler() {//начало функции-обработчика
    var data = document.getElementById('in_1c').value;//получил и записал в переменную данные из textarea
    var position = document.querySelector('.container');//записал в переменную родителя
    //проверка, если поле textarea не пустое, то вставить и вывести данные, иначе сообщение об ошибке
    if (data != 0) {
        //вставка данных в конец родителя ".container"
      position.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="data">${data.split(/\s/).map(m=>`<li>${m.toUpperCase()}</li>`).join('')}</ul>
        </div>
      `);//данные разделяются по пробелу регулярным выражением и изменяются другими методами
        /* 
            1) .join() - объединяет все элементы массива (или массивоподобного объекта) в строку.
            2) .toUpperCase() - возвращает значение строки с преобразованием в верхний регистр
            3) .map() - создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива.
            4) .split() - разбивает объект string на массив строк путём разделения указанной подстрокой или как в моем случае с помощью регулярного выражения
        */
      var buttonClose = document.querySelector('button.close');//записал в переменную элемент кнопка
      var parentElem = buttonClose.parentNode;//записал в переменную родительский элемент 
      buttonClose.addEventListener('click', removeChildren); //добавил событие на кнопку, присвоил обработчик "removeChildren"
      function removeChildren() { //обработчик
        while (parentElem.lastChild) { //цикл для удаления всех дочерних элементов
          parentElem.removeChild(parentElem.lastChild);
        }
      }

    }
    else { //сообщение об ошибке
      var warningEl = document.createElement('div'); //создание элемента
      warningEl.setAttribute('class', 'warning'); //создание атрибута
      var message = document.createTextNode('Пожалуйста, заполните соотвествующие поля для обработки!'); //создание текстового узла
      warningEl.appendChild(message); //закрепляем текстовый узел в созданном элементе
      var e = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]; //получил в перемиенную родительский элемент
      e.appendChild(warningEl); //установка нового элемента на заданную позицию (по умолчанию ставится в конец)
      
    }
  }
```

```css
.header {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.warning {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:2rem;
    background: #F08080;
    color: floralwhite;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.data {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ced4da;
}
.close {
    position: relative;
    right: -10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.close:focus {outline: none;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h2 class="header">Обработчик</h2>
       <!--<form action="">-->
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"><!--d-flex-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="in_1c">Номенклатура из 1С (например: RS-CS18AX/RU-18AX1)</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="in_1c" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <p class="text-right mt-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick="resetValue1();" value="Очистить"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="in_price">Номенклатура из прайса</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="in_price" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <p class="text-right mt-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick="resetValue2();" value="Очистить"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Отправить</button></div>
             </div>
        <!--</form>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/j79d7d

Comment: Ну добавьте в текст вопроса же!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в этой строчке:

```
var buttonClose = document.querySelector('button.close');
```

Когда вы добавляете вторую кнопку, этот селектор опять возвращает вам первую.

Можно сделать общий обработчик для кнопок удаления, вместо того чтоб каждый раз его вешать:

```
document.querySelector('.container').onclick = e => {
  if (e.target.matches('button.close')) {
    const parentElem = e.target.parentNode;
    while (parentElem.lastChild) { //цикл для удаления всех дочерних элементов
      parentElem.removeChild(parentElem.lastChild);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Родительские элементы у всех кнопок разные и их нужно не записывать в переменную, а вычислять внутри функции нажатия на кнопку.
Вдобавок у вас определялась первая кнопка и ей присваивалась функция. А нужно было брать последнюю кнопку. Но раз вы код кнопки вставляете текстом по моему проще и обработчик вставить текстом.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');//записал в переменную кнопку "Отправить"
  submit.addEventListener('click', handler);//добавляем событие и обработчик

function removeParent(e) { //обработчик
  var parentElem = e.parentNode; //определяем родителя
  parentElem.parentNode.removeChild(parentElem); //удаляем элемент
}

  function handler() {//начало функции-обработчика
    var data = document.getElementById('in_1c').value;//получил и записал в переменную данные из textarea
    var position = document.querySelector('.container');//записал в переменную родителя
    //проверка, если поле textarea не пустое, то вставить и вывести данные, иначе сообщение об ошибке
    if (data != 0) {
        //вставка данных в конец родителя ".container"
      position.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="removeParent(this);">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="data">${data.split(/\s/).map(m=>`<li>${m.toUpperCase()}</li>`).join('')}</ul>
        </div>
      `);//данные разделяются по пробелу регулярным выражением и изменяются другими методами
        /* 
            1) .join() - объединяет все элементы массива (или массивоподобного объекта) в строку.
            2) .toUpperCase() - возвращает значение строки с преобразованием в верхний регистр
            3) .map() - создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива.
            4) .split() - разбивает объект string на массив строк путём разделения указанной подстрокой или как в моем случае с помощью регулярного выражения
        */
      //var buttonClose = document.querySelector('button.close');//тут вообще нужно брать последнюю кнопку а тут берется первая поэтому и проблема
      //buttonClose.addEventListener('click', removeChildren); //добавил событие на кнопку, присвоил обработчик "removeChildren"
    }
    else { //сообщение об ошибке
      var warningEl = document.createElement('div'); //создание элемента
      warningEl.setAttribute('class', 'warning'); //создание атрибута
      var message = document.createTextNode('Пожалуйста, заполните соотвествующие поля для обработки!'); //создание текстового узла
      warningEl.appendChild(message); //закрепляем текстовый узел в созданном элементе
      var e = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]; //получил в перемиенную родительский элемент
      e.appendChild(warningEl); //установка нового элемента на заданную позицию (по умолчанию ставится в конец)
      
    }
  }
```

```css
.header {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.warning {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:2rem;
    background: #F08080;
    color: floralwhite;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.data {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ced4da;
}
.close {
    position: relative;
    right: -10px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.close:focus {outline: none;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h2 class="header">Обработчик</h2>
       <!--<form action="">-->
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6"><!--d-flex-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="in_1c">Номенклатура из 1С (например: RS-CS18AX/RU-18AX1)</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="in_1c" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <p class="text-right mt-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick="resetValue1();" value="Очистить"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="in_price">Номенклатура из прайса</label>
                        <textarea name="" id="in_price" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <p class="text-right mt-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick="resetValue2();" value="Очистить"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Отправить</button></div>
             </div>
        <!--</form>-->
</div>
```